# Call stored procedure in loop for different values of the argument POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which accepts single varchar argument, I want to call this for each distinct id present in my table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateData(i varchar(12)) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
      update employee set employee_number = nextval('d_employeeNumber_seq') where employee.age > 25 and employee.deptId = i;
     ALTER SEQUENCE d_employeeNumber_seq RESTART WITH 1;   
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now I want to call this updateData() for each department

something like `select updateData() in (select distinct deptId from employee)`  [This isnt the correct syntax but i want to use something of this sort]

Comment: what you have is a `function` and not a `stored procedure`. Syntax to invoke `stored procedure` is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a subquery and to pass the desired parameter:

```
select updateData(deptID)
from ( select distinct deptId  from employee) a
```

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty straight forward.